# How to configure Sender-ID in Postfix?

Tags: linux, postfix

when I send an email to @hotmail I see this line on the source:

```
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; sender-id=temperror (sender IP is xx.xxx.xxx.xxx) header.from=email@example.com; dkim=pass header.d=example.com; x-hmca=pass
```

As you can see there is `sender-id=temperror`, how can I do to pass it?

I have SPF, DKIM, RDNS...how to add this sender-id ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hotmail does not use live DNS for Sender ID. They have a DNS cache that they update twice per day. All TempError means is that your domain's SPF record is not in their cache. To get your record added to their cache, send an e-mail message to senderid@microsoft.com with your domain in it. They will add it, but be patient as it's a manual process and the cache only updates twice a day.

Source of the aforementioned information: http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Hotmail_and_TempError

Answer (score 0):

You now have to submit your domain to their Sender ID cache here:

https://support.msn.com/default.aspx?productKey=senderid&locale=en-us&st=1&wfxredirect=1

Comment: As of April 2012 they rely on SPF records.